# Nesting a myqsql query in side a while query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to pull additional information about an inventory items from my products table by matching up their model.

I want to run another query from the products table inside this while loop where model=$model. From there i want to get variables like price to display in my `$inventory_list`

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventory order by model");
    // get all the product details
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
         $model = $row["model"];
         $serial = $row["serial"];
         $inventory_list .= "$model $serial <br />";
         }
```

Is using another table for inventory necessary if I need to keep track of serials? 
Any and all help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to `JOIN` the `inventory` and `products` tables together in order to achieve the same result through a single query, lessening network overhead.

It should look something like this:

```
SELECT `inventory`.*, `products`.`price`
FROM `inventory`
LEFT JOIN `products` ON `inventory`.`model` = `product`.`model`
ORDER BY `inventory`.`model`;
```

**JOIN Reference**: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to join both tables and return data, this way you don't have to call another query in while loop and thereby increase performance and reduce calls to database

Ex:

```
SELECT i.* , p.price
FROM inventory i
JOIN products p on i.model = p.model
order by i.model
```